# Append total rows for 2 out of 3 items in object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix

I need help with this matrix algorithm:

Input:

```
const reqObj = [
    ['Anna', 'Class', 'Cycling', '10'],
    ['Anna', 'Class', 'Boxing', '25'],
    ['Anna', 'Class', 'Climbing', '20'],
    ['Anna', 'Misc', 'Towel', '5'],
    ['Anna', 'Drink', 'Coffee', '3'],
    ['Anna', 'Drink', 'Tea', '4'],
    ['Beatrice', 'Drink', 'Tea', '4'],
    ['Beatrice', 'Class', 'Kickboxing', '25'],
    ['Beatrice', 'Misc', 'Lock', '20'],
    ['Beatrice', 'Misc', 'Towel', '5']
]
```

Expected output:

```
const resObj = [
    ['Anna', 'Class', 'Cycling', '10'],
    ['Anna', 'Class', 'Boxing', '25'],
    ['Anna', 'Class', 'Climbing', '20'],
    ['Anna', 'Misc', 'Towel', '5'],
    ['Anna', 'Drink', 'Coffee', '3'],
    ['Anna', 'Drink', 'Tea', '4'],
    ['Anna', 'Class', 'Total classes', '55'],
    ['Anna', 'Drink', 'Total drinks', '7'],
    ['Beatrice', 'Drink', 'Tea', '4'],
    ['Beatrice', 'Class', 'Kickboxing', '25'],
    ['Beatrice', 'Misc', 'Lock', '20'],
    ['Beatrice', 'Misc', 'Towel', '5'],
    ['Beatrice', 'Class', 'Total classes', '25'],
    ['Beatrice', 'Drink', 'Total drinks', '4']
]
```

In words:

- Loop through object array contains data of several people.
- If the same person, the same service (which is not Misc), get the **sum** of **service cost**, replace **service name** with **total name**, and append to the bottom of the rows contain that person's data.

Here's my code:

```
const totalRow = arr => {
    let result = [].concat(...arr.reduce((acc, [person, service, type, amount]) => {
            let data = acc.get(person) || [[person, service, type, '0']]
            if (service === 'Class') data.push([person, service, 'Total classes', amount])
            else if (service === 'Drink') data.push([person, service, 'Total drinks', amount])
            data[0][3] = (+data[0][3] + +amount).toString()
            return acc.set(person, data)
        }, new Map)
        .values()
    )

    return result
}

const totalRowResult = totalRow(reqObj)

console.log(totalRowResult)
```

### Update

Output with negative sum:

```
const resObj = [
    ['Anna', 'Class', 'Cycling', '10'],
    ['Anna', 'Class', 'Boxing', '25'],
    ['Anna', 'Class', 'Climbing', '20'],
    ['Anna', 'Misc', 'Towel', '5'],
    ['Anna', 'Drink', 'Coffee', '3'],
    ['Anna', 'Drink', 'Tea', '4'],
    ['Anna', 'Class', 'Total classes', '-55'],
    ['Anna', 'Drink', 'Total drinks', '-7'],
    ['Beatrice', 'Drink', 'Tea', '4'],
    ['Beatrice', 'Class', 'Kickboxing', '25'],
    ['Beatrice', 'Misc', 'Lock', '20'],
    ['Beatrice', 'Misc', 'Towel', '5'],
    ['Beatrice', 'Class', 'Total classes', '-25'],
    ['Beatrice', 'Drink', 'Total drinks', '-4']
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use groups in the map for the services to get the total costs.

```js
var array = [['Anna', 'Class', 'Cycling', '10'], ['Anna', 'Class', 'Boxing', '25'], ['Anna', 'Class', 'Climbing', '20'], ['Anna', 'Misc', 'Towel', '5'], ['Anna', 'Drink', 'Coffee', '3'], ['Anna', 'Drink', 'Tea', '4'], ['Beatrice', 'Drink', 'Tea', '4'], ['Beatrice', 'Class', 'Kickboxing', '25'], ['Beatrice', 'Misc', 'Lock', '20'], ['Beatrice', 'Misc', 'Towel', '5']],
    plurals = { class: 'classes' },
    result = [].concat(...Array.from(array
        .reduce((m, a) => {
            var [person, service, type, cost] = a,
                data = m.get(person) || { _: [], i: 0 };

            data._.splice(data.i++, 0, a);
            if (service !== 'Misc') {
                if (!data[service]) {
                    data[service] = [person, service, 'Total ' + (plurals[service.toLowerCase()] || service.toLowerCase() + 's'), '0'];
                    data._.push(data[service]);
                }
                data[service][3] = (+data[service][3] + +cost).toString();
            }
            return m.set(person, data);
        }, new Map)
        .values(), ({ _ }) => _)
    );

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result.map(a => a.join(' ')), 0, 4) + '</pre>');

console.log(result.map(a => a.join(' ')));
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you Nina Scholz. I understand that you handle the string for Total with an object, but what if the total string is named differently without the class in it, for example:
if service = class => 'Total gym expense'
if service = drink => 'Total cafe expense'
How would you handle that?

Comment: Also, I like the fact that you prefer 1 line code, and I've been using console.log to understand your code like: { _: [], i: 0 } and  .values(), ({ _ }) => _) it'd be great if you could explain to me a bit more.

Comment: ad1: youcould use an object as for plurals and inser the wanted phrase in. ad 2: i took the underscore as key, because in the same object are some other keys of `service`. this undercore property is later mapped for the result.

Comment: Hi @Nina Scholz. An extra question: how would you change the sum value of the total row to the opposite? Example: ['Anna', 'Class', 'Total classes', '-55'] instead of '55'?

Comment: with subtracting from total ...?

Comment: No. For example, the total expense for Classes is 55, but I need the result as -55 (minus 55) to balance the big total later. I've tried adding the minus sign in the code but it either returns NaN or wrong sum. I've edited my question above.

Comment: Oh. Never mind. I've figured it out. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: data[service][3] = (-data[service][3]*(-1) - -cost*(-1)).toString();

Comment: take this line: `data[service][3] = (data[service][3] - cost).toString();`

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```
// Your input data
const input = [
  ['Anna', 'Class', 'Cycling', '10'],
  ['Anna', 'Class', 'Boxing', '25'],
  ['Anna', 'Class', 'Climbing', '20'],
  ['Anna', 'Misc', 'Towel', '5'],
  ['Anna', 'Drink', 'Coffee', '3'],
  ['Anna', 'Drink', 'Tea', '4'],
  ['Beatrice', 'Drink', 'Tea', '4'],
  ['Beatrice', 'Class', 'Kickboxing', '25'],
  ['Beatrice', 'Misc', 'Lock', '20'],
  ['Beatrice', 'Misc', 'Towel', '5']
];

// Returns all items which contain the given name
const getAllPersonsItems = name => input.filter(currentItem => currentItem[0] === name);

// Returns all items which contain the given name and item
const getPersonsItems = (name, item) => getAllPersonsItems(name).filter(currentItem => currentItem[1] === item);

// Returns total of given items (template string is used to return the total as a string - not number)
const getItemsTotal = items => `${items.reduce((acc, cur) => parseInt(cur[3], 10) + acc, 0)}`;

// Returns all existing names
const names = input.reduce((acc, cur) => acc.indexOf(cur[0]) > -1 ? acc : [cur[0], ...acc], []);

// Loops through each name and creates items totals
const totals = names.reduce((acc, name) => acc
  .concat(getAllPersonsItems(name))
  .concat([
    [name, 'class', 'Total classes', getItemsTotal(getPersonsItems(name, 'Class'))],
    [name, 'drink', 'Total drinks', getItemsTotal(getPersonsItems(name, 'Drink'))],
  ]), []);

// Logs your desired output
console.log(totals);
```